# Guice Constructor Injection withOUT Annotations?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Can someone help with an implementation of Guice withOUT annotations?

```
public interface IAnimal {
  void makeNoise();
}


public interface IVehicle {
  int getWheelCount();
}





import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
public class Car implements IVehicle {

    private Log Logger;

    public Car(Log lgr) {
        this.Logger = lgr;
    }

    public final int getWheelCount() {
      this.Logger.info("getWheelCount is returning 4");
      return 4;
    }
}




import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
public class Dog implements IAnimal {

    private Log Logger;

    public Dog(Log lgr) {
        this.Logger = lgr;
    }

    public final void makeNoise() {
        this.Logger.info("Bark Bark Bark");
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

What I've tried:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import com.google.inject.*;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Log localLogger = 
        LogFactory.getLog(App.class);

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();

    IVehicle veh = injector.getInstance(Car.class);  
    int wc = veh.getWheelCount();

    IAnimal amh = injector.getInstance(Dog.class);  
    amh.makeNoise();
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
```

I understand the error.

But I'm hoping I can "point" Guice to the correct constructor......instead of using the annotation.

As you can see, using a default/empty constructor is not a good option, as this example is simple, but I want to stick with constructor based inject.

APPEND:

Based on the "hint" I got from Hemant Singh in the comments, I think I got closer.

I created a ProductionInjectModule, that uses

```
bind(MyInterface.class).toConstructor(MyConcrete.class.getConstructor(org.apache.commons.logging.Log.class));
```

But even though I am "forcing" the issue by pointing to a specific constructor (using "toConstructor").......I'm still getting:

> Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with
>   @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.

Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!

Full "module" code below:

```
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    runGuice();

  }

  private static void runGuice() {
    Log localLogger = LogFactory.getLog(App.class);

    ProductionInjectModule pm = new ProductionInjectModule(localLogger);
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(pm);
    ////Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
    //// injector.injectMembers(localLogger);

    IVehicle veh = injector.getInstance(Car.class);
    int wc = veh.getWheelCount();

    IAnimal amh = injector.getInstance(Dog.class);
    amh.makeNoise();
  }

 }




import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Module;

public class ProductionInjectModule extends AbstractModule implements Module {
  // public void configure(Binder binder) {
  // binder.bind(IVehicle.class).to(Car.class);
  //// binder.bind(InterfaceB.class).to(ConcreteB.class);
  //// binder.bind(InterfaceC.class).to(ConcreteC.class);
  // }

  private final org.apache.commons.logging.Log Logger;

  public ProductionInjectModule(org.apache.commons.logging.Log concreteLogger) {
    this.Logger = concreteLogger;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    try {
      bind(org.apache.commons.logging.Log.class).toInstance(this.Logger);
      bind(IVehicle.class).toConstructor(Car.class.getConstructor(org.apache.commons.logging.Log.class));
      bind(IAnimal.class).toConstructor(Dog.class.getConstructor(org.apache.commons.logging.Log.class));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      addError(e);
    }
  }

}
```

And following the same hint, I found some documentation to support:

from : http://www.baeldung.com/guice

> You can also inject a dependency that doesn’t have a default no-arg
>   constructor using constructor binding:

```
>     public class BasicModule extends AbstractModule {
>   
>     @Override
>     protected void configure() {
>         bind(Boolean.class).toInstance(true);
>         bind(Communication.class).toConstructor(
>           Communication.class.getConstructor(Boolean.TYPE)); }
```

> ```
> The snippet above will inject an instance of Communication using the
> ```
>
> constructor that takes a boolean argument. We supply the true argument
>   to the constructor by defining an untargeted binding of the Boolean
>   class.
>
> This untargeted binding will be eagerly supplied to any constructor in
>   the binding that accepts a boolean parameter. With this approach, all
>   dependencies of Communication are injected.
>
> Another approach to constructor-specific binding is the instance
>   binding, where we provide an instance directly in the binding:

```
>     public class BasicModule extends AbstractModule {
>   
>     @Override
>     protected void configure() {
>         bind(Communication.class)
>           .toInstance(new Communication(true));
>     }     }
```

**Summer 2019 APPEND:**

It would be wiser to use "slf4j" instead of "org.apache.commons"

```
org.slf4j.Logger 
and
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Why?

https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

> Embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare
>   a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a
>   library declares a compile-time dependency on a SLF4J binding, it
>   imposes that binding on the end-user, thus negating SLF4J's purpose.
>   When you come across an embedded component declaring a compile-time
>   dependency on any SLF4J binding, please take the time to contact the
>   authors of said component/library and kindly ask them to mend their
>   ways.

Comment: I think you can solve the problem using, https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings

Comment: @HemantSingh  You got me closer.  Thank you.  I appended my answer.  Even though I'm saying "use this constructor", it's still giving me a hard time.  It ~should work.

Comment: I got it  !   Thanks @HemantSingh

Comment: Who downvoted this?  Any why?  #downvotingNeedsAccountability

Comment: Not me, btw I upvoted it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it!  My "APPEND:" area in the original question was close!  But now I see my small mistake.

My ProductionInjectModule above was correct.

My "ask to resolve" was wrong.

Notice in my getInstance, I still had the concrete.

I needed to have this: (emphasis on the argument of the getInstance)

```
IVehicle veh = injector.getInstance(IVehicle.class);
int wc = veh.getWheelCount();

IAnimal amh = injector.getInstance(IAnimal.class);
amh.makeNoise();
```

Full working code: (with the interfaces and concretes from above)

```
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    runGuice();

  }

  private static void runGuice() {
    Log localLogger = LogFactory.getLog(App.class);

    ProductionInjectModule pm = new ProductionInjectModule(localLogger);
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(pm);

    IVehicle veh = injector.getInstance(IVehicle.class);
    int wc = veh.getWheelCount();

    IAnimal amh = injector.getInstance(IAnimal.class);
    amh.makeNoise();
  }

 }




import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Module;

public class ProductionInjectModule extends AbstractModule implements Module {

  private final org.apache.commons.logging.Log Logger;

  public ProductionInjectModule(org.apache.commons.logging.Log concreteLogger) {
    this.Logger = concreteLogger;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    try {
      bind(org.apache.commons.logging.Log.class).toInstance(this.Logger);
      bind(IVehicle.class).toConstructor(Car.class.getConstructor(org.apache.commons.logging.Log.class));
      bind(IAnimal.class).toConstructor(Dog.class.getConstructor(org.apache.commons.logging.Log.class));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      addError(e);
    }
  }

}
```

**Summer 2019 APPEND:**

It would be wiser to use "slf4j" instead of "org.apache.commons"

```
org.slf4j.Logger 
and
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course, check for more recent update:

https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.slf4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22slf4j-api%22

Why?

https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

> Embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare
>   a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a
>   library declares a compile-time dependency on a SLF4J binding, it
>   imposes that binding on the end-user, thus negating SLF4J's purpose.
>   When you come across an embedded component declaring a compile-time
>   dependency on any SLF4J binding, please take the time to contact the
>   authors of said component/library and kindly ask them to mend their
>   ways.